# How to trun on graphics acceleration (kernel-module-imx-gpu-viv) on i.Mx6Q (buildroot)?

Tags: qt, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, buildroot, imx6

I enter these command on i.Mx6Q (Buildroot) with qt5

```
# export QT_QPA_EGLFS_INTEGRATION=eglfs_viv
# CinematicExperience-demo -platform eglfs
```

The demo app run normally, but it shows:

```
qt.qpa.egldeviceintegration: Failed to load EGL device integration "eglfs_viv"
```

I found [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/83241/bad-performance-after-moving-from-android-4-2-to-lubuntu-14-04-with-imx6/3) said this error means I don't have graphics acceleration on your board.

And [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/73383/could-not-open-egl-display/7) said that I need to turn on

```
kernel-module-imx-gpu-viv
libgles2-mx6
libegl-mx6
```

Finally, I found [this](http://buildroot-busybox.2317881.n4.nabble.com/RFC-kernel-module-imx-gpu-viv-compaling-error-td171162.html) said the kernel version have to from 3.10.x to 4.1.x.
So I change it to 4.1.15 like this in menuconfig (original version is 4.14.14):

```
Kernel version (Custom Git repository)
(git://git.freescale.com/imx/linux-imx.git)URL of custom repository
(rel_imx_4.1.15_2.0.0_ga)Custom repository version
(imx_v7_mfg)Defconfig name
(board/freescale/imx6-sabresd/linux_qt5.fragment)Additional configuration fragment files
Kernel binary format(zImage)
[*]Build a Device Tree Blob(DTB)
(imx6q-sabresd)Device Tree Source file names
```

It compile successfully, but when I deploy on SD Card and try to run QT demo it shows:

```
qt.qpa.egldeviceintegration: Failed to load EGL device integration "eglfs_viv"
MESA-LOADER: failed to retrieve device information
gbm: failed to open any driver (search paths /usr/lib/dri)
gbm: Last dlopen error: File not found
failed to load driver: vivante
drmModeGetResources failed
Segmentation fault
```

### Questions:

How to turn on graphics acceleration on i.Mx6Q (Buildroot)?
Does turn on 'kernel-module-imx-gpu-viv' is the right step? If it's right, than how to set the kernel to lower version to run QT demo successfully?

Comment: Take a look at an older Buildroot and kernel config for i.MX6Q at http://forums.wandboard.org/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=991  Besides the kernel driver, you need libraries in userspace.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with kernel 4.1 but it was using Yocto Project branch rocko and Qt5.9.

Run the `ldd /path_your_app/app_qt` with your application and place the output here.

Run `zcat /proc/config.gz` and put the output here.